# Manifest v3 background service worker seems to go stale. How to verify this is the case

Tags: google-chrome-extension, service-worker, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

My goal is to make sure I have a stable process for handling extension updates. I'm about to release a new extension and have noticed that the background service worker goes stale. Here are the details:

My method of testing this lifecycle is by generating a new build artifact and drag-n-dropping it into the page `chrome://extensions`. I hope this is the way to test this lifecycle. But if not, I would be happy to hear the alternative.

Once I drag and drop, I open the background console to check for the correct version, but seems it lags behind. The only way to remedy this issue is by removing the extension completely and loading it back, this gives me the impression a regular user would experience the same issue.

The screenshot below describes the situation:

1. version `0.3.33` is currently installed
2. drag and drop new build version `0.3.34`
3. after successful drag and drop, notice version is lagging with version `0.3.31`
4. But the `chrome.runtime.onInstall` release accurately outputs the previous version

[image: stale version screenshot]

Furthermore, I took a look at the unpacked extension directory and the compiled code is accurate with the expected version

[image: verification on unloaded source directory]

What I've done so far to troubleshoot, was to remove the extension completely. It does successfully update after a series of `manifest.version` updates, but then it goes stale. To be clear, all I do is update the `version` property of the `manifest.json` file and that seems to cause this issue

Any help would be greatly appreciated. In the meantime, I'll brush up on the architecture for service workers as it relates to chrome manifest v3. Thanks!

---

### EDIT - Sunday, August 22 2021:

The latest development:
First of all, thanks woxxom for additional details to debug.

I've created an example project that demonstrates the problem with reproducible steps. Hopefully, this helps identify the problem but it does seem to point to a Chrome bug so I'll also report it on crbug.com

Github project: https://github.com/miguelespinoza/-v3-service-worker-update

Ultimately, what I've identified is that loading an iframe causes the service worker lifecycle to go "stale".

Looking at `chrome://serviceworker-internals/?devtools`, I've noticed that the extension includes two workers, that seems odd because I'd imagine only one should exist, the one in the background. This could mean nothing, but wanted to share that as well. one "Active worker" and one "Waiting worker"

[image]

Important Note: Service worker background events stop working. In my case, `chrome.commands.onCommand` or `chrome.action.onClicked`

Comment: The question lacks an [MCVE](/help/mcve). So far it sounds like either a bug in Chrome, which you can report on https://crbug.com, or a mistake in your code e.g. maybe you register the service worker explicitly via navigator.serviceWorker, in which case don't do it. Note that if your background script was already non-persistent and you didn't use DOM or getBackgroundPage, then you don't need to learn anything about service workers, it should just work seamlessly.

Comment: As for verifying, open any page of your extension (e.g. the popup), open devtools there, switch to `Application` tab, then `service worker` on the left. You'll see its lifecycle events there.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I've included a project in the question with reproducible steps. It took some trial and error to identify the issue, but it boils down to an iframe loaded on a webpage causing the issue.

Hard to say why this causes the service worker to go "stale" but it definitely causes a weird side effect with service workers not working at all

Comment: Bug reported: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1242225


I probably should add an important component to this. Service worker events stop working.  In my case chrome.commands.onCommand and chrome.action.onClicked. This could help to escalate the problem

Comment: I'm happy to help in further debugging this issue. Let me know how I can help, if you would need more information. 

Unfortunately, this is a show-stopper. I'm going to see what kind of workaround I can take

Comment: lol, I'm commenting, assuming you work with the Chromium team. I've seen you, @wOxxOm throughout my career building Chrome Extensions. You're everywhere! and you've saved me a few times while in a rabbit hole. Happy you're still around! I recently quit my 9-5 to work as an indie dev. Naturally, decided to build a browser extension. So I'm happy to help identify the cause of this issue. Not sure what the process is like after submitting a bug, so would be happy to know more about it. I hit this unexpected blocker, so anything that can help expedite this issue, I'd be happy to do

Comment: I'm not affiliated with the Chromium team but I'll keep an eye on that bug report.

Comment: Gotcha, that's cool. Yeh same. Looks like it's getting triaged so will keep an eye for next steps.